# What is the capital gains tax on stocks in Netherlands?

Tags: capital-gains-tax, netherlands

Pretty simple question - but I have read conflicting pieces saying in some cases capital gains is 0% in Netherlands and other places that it is 25%.

Can anyone share details on the rate of capital gains in the Netherlands for an individual?  (in this case for stocks). I am a resident of Netherlands and live and work here.

Thanks

**Edit**:  To complicate this a bit further, I have the Dutch 30% Ruling and am reading that I [can opt for partial non-residency status](https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontenten/belastingdienst/individuals/living_and_working/working_in_another_country_temporarily/you_are_coming_to_work_in_the_netherlands/partial_non_resident_taxpayer_status/)

> Consequences for income tax:
>   If you opt for partial non-resident taxpayer status, your taxable income from a substantial interest (box 2) and your taxable income from savings and investments (box 3) will, for income tax purposes, be determined according to the regulations that apply to non-resident taxpayer status. In practice, this means that, for these boxes, tax is levied on a lower amount. As a result, you pay less tax.

I am now trying to understand how this will effect it.

Comment: The [KPMG site summary of taxes in The Netherlands](https://home.kpmg/xx/en/home/insights/2011/12/Netherlands-income-tax.html) states that, for residents of The Netherlands, "*Dividends and capital gains are taxed at a flat rate of 25 percent.*"

Comment: @NickR only when it is a "substantial interest" aka >5% share of company

Answer (score 2):

```
Written before Question edit.
```

If you have more than 5% of the shares in a company:

> Taxable income under Box 2 category includes dividends and capital
>   gains from a substantial shareholding. (inkomsten uit aanmerkelijk
>   belang) (i.e. a shareholding of at least 5%) Income that falls into
>   the Box 2 category is taxed at a flat rate of 25%
>   [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_gains_tax)

If you have less than 5% of the shares in a company, you pay no dividend or capital gain tax.

(There is a dividend tax but you can request them to return it to you so effective 0% for dutch citizens)

Your wealth is taxed:

> (box 3) taxable income from savings and investments (viz. real estate) However
>   a "theoretical capital yield" of 4% is taxed at a rate of 30% (so
>   1.2%) but only if the savings plus stocks of a person exceed a threshold of 25.000 euros. This will be raised to a threshold of
>   30.000 euros in 2018, together with other changes so that people with less wealth, pay lower taxes
>   [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_gains_tax)

They recently (effective from 2017) changed the system. To make it more fair, or at least they try.

It exists of a savings part and an investment part.

For the saving part they changed the 4% to 0,13%
For the investment part it was changed from 4% to 5,6%

Still there don't take the facts but make an expectation which is the same for each citizen.

Until € 71.650 67% is considerd savings and 33% is considered investment

So the effective rate is 1,935%

From € 71.651 until € 989.736 21% savings and 79% investment totals in 4,451%

From € 989.737 100% invesmtent totals in 5,60%

The rate change a bit yearly to reflect the real world(this are the rates for 2019)

[Dutch Source](https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontentnl/belastingdienst/prive/vermogen_en_aanmerkelijk_belang/vermogen/belasting_betalen_over_uw_vermogen/grondslag_sparen_en_beleggen/berekening-2019/)

Comment: Yes and that means "if you have significant assets move the ***** out of the country". I was repeatedly offered to work in the Netherlands but I would literally have had to pay more wealth tax than they where willing to pay me before taxes. NO way. THere are VERY few countries taxing wealth these days.

Comment: @TomTom yes it is high taxes here.  but hoping the 30% ruling can help this

Comment: Hardly. I pay 18% capital gains tax where I live with ZERO wealth tax. As a high net worth individual the 30% rule alone makes me work in my day job for basically nothing - only to pay my wealth tax. Ridiculous. Threshhold of 25ooo EUR? Sure. That is no threshhold, that is "no money in the bank" level once you are not a student.

Answer (score 1):

> The main difference is the scope of the tax liability: resident
>   taxpayers are in essence subject to tax for their world-wide income,
>   whereas non-resident taxpayers are only subject to tax for certain
>   specific categories of income from Dutch source.

[Source](https://www.tax-consultants-international.com/read/taxation-non-resident-taxpayers-netherlands?submenu=13169&sublist=3275&subsublist=3300)